# Setting up Nginx Reverse Proxy for MongoDB Connection - Connection Timeout Issue

Tags: mongodb, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am attempting to configure Nginx as a reverse proxy for accessing a MongoDB database hosted on a cluster. I have tried different configurations using the HTTP server block and Stream module, but I'm encountering a connection timeout issue when trying to connect using MongoDB Compass.

Here are the details of my setup:

**MongoDB Connection String:**

`mongodb+srv://username:password@my-domain.something.mongodb.net/database-name`

**Nginx HTTP Server Block Configuration:**

```
server {
    proxy_pass "my-domain.something.mongodb.net"; # This is my SRV
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

**Nginx Stream Block Configuration:**

```
server {
    listen 27017;
    proxy_pass my-domain-shard-00-00.something.mongodb.net:27017; # Using MongoDB shard URL
    proxy_timeout 60s;
}
```

**Connection String Used in MongoDB Compass:**
`mongodb://username:password@proxy-domain.com:27017/database-name`

However, the connection to the MongoDB cluster through the Nginx proxy results in a timeout error.

Any insights into what might be causing the connection timeout or suggestions for improvements in my Nginx configuration would be greatly appreciated.

**Basically, I'm trying to set proxy on my mongodb. which is hosted on cluster.**